# How to inject the .NET Core [IServiceProvider] itself into services?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How to inject the [IServiceProvider] interface into custom services? I mean after the [Startup] class finishes construction of [IServiceProvider] from [IServiceCollection] set of bindings. How do I then subscribe to the newly created [IServiceProvider] built after method [ConfigureServices] invoked?

Comment: `IServiceProvider` is injectable into custom services, have you even tried it first?

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is usually ill-advised to explicitly inject `IServiceProvider` into services and may be a code smell

Comment: I see now. I can use a factory delegate to pass the [IServiceProvider]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your service inside startup you should create a scope

```
// initial database
        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            var initDatabase = new YourClass(scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourServiceInterface>());
        }
```

But Accessing to IServiceProvider in other services don't make sense. If you describe more You could get the right answer.